# Google sheets python api not reading cells correctly

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

So, my problem is simple, when I read the cells I need in my script, the script for some reason says that a cell is empty when it is not, for example I always read cell "C4" but the script still says that it is empty even when it is not.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# get the instance of the Spreadsheet
sheet = client.open('Copy of Event Organizer')

# get the first sheet of the Spreadsheet
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)

words = ["C4", "C5", "C7", "C9", "C11", "C13", "C15", "C17", "C19", "C21", "C23", "C25"]
values = [1012, 12317, 1120, 1345, 134, 1120, 1420, 5, 531, 220, 15, 2354]

len_list = []
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    try:
        len_list.append(len(sheet_instance.acell(word).value))

    except:
        len_list.append(0)
    len_list[i] = len_list[i] * values[i]

print(len_list)
print(sum(len_list))
sheet_instance.update_acell("C29", sum(len_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you want to get the first sheet in your spreadsheet and check it's cell values depending on the declared `words` variable. But you are actually reading your `fourth sheet` in your spreadsheet.

**Your code:**

```
# get the first sheet of the Spreadsheet
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)
```

---

### [**Selecting a Worksheet**](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)

- You might want to reconsider using index when you are selecting your sheet, since there is a tendency that your spreadsheet might get re-arrange. The most safest way to select a worksheet is by its `title/Sheet name`

Select worksheet by index. Worksheet indexes start from zero:

```
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
```

Or by title:

```
worksheet = sh.worksheet("January")
```

Or the most common case: Sheet1:

```
worksheet = sh.sheet1
```